# Unzip with the Pipe Viewer

Tags: 16.04, pipe, unzip

I'm trying to use Pipe Viewer (`pv`) while extracting files from zip archive.

Now I'm using

```
unzip -o -q myfile.zip -d test
```

So I tried something like (solution seen for tar)

```
pv myfile.zip | unzip -o -q - -d test
```

But it's not working.  What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is not the syntax, but the build-in difference between tar and zip.

The problem with submitting zip file via pipe is based on [zip design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29)

> **A directory is placed at the end of a .ZIP file**. This identifies what files are in the .ZIP and identifies where in the .ZIP that file
>   is located. This allows .ZIP readers to load the list of files without
>   reading the entire .ZIP archive

When providing zip via pipe - the directory will be accessed only after the entire file will be supplied by the pipe, hence `pv` should be completed before unzip should start - which cause the failure you are facing.

Comment: @tweetysat - can you try using other format than `zip` - which won't require downloading the entire file in order to start working on it?

Answer (score 0):

Take `bsdtar` for using unzip via pipe. Example:

```
$ sudo apt install libarchive-tools

$ wget -qO- https://dl.1001fonts.com/breitkopf-fraktur.zip |sudo bsdtar -xvf- -C /usr/local/share/fonts/
```

Comment: The PO would like to see a progress bar while extracting an archive using the command `pv`. Where is `pv` in your solution? Could you improve it?